# Symfony 2 default value for many to to many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have little problem with relation many to many.
I want to set default entity when I create user.

For example I have two entities.
User and Project ( user can have many projects, project can have many users )

In my database I have project with ID = 1;

Now when I create new user and I don't choose any project I want to check it in my User entity.  I don't know how can I get instance of Project class where id = 1?

Do I have to doctrine manager or something like that?
Can someone help me?

I want to do it in entity without controller.

> for the PrePersist event

But how can I get instanceof project with id = 1 in user entity?

Answer (score 0):

Using PrePersist

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $args->getEntity(); //User entity
    if ($entity->getProject() == NULL) { //this would check if Project is empty, meaning no project was selected upon creation of the user and associate project with id = 1
        $project = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Project')->find(1); //Project Entity
        $entity->setProject($project);
    }
}
```

Comment: A nicer solution should be to add a LifecycleCallback on the entity, for the PrePersist event. With it, we keep the controller clean and move the logic in the object. But your solution is still functionnal.

Comment: thanks for answer. 

I want to do it in entity without controller. 

>  for the PrePersist event

But how can I get instance of project with id = 1 in user entity?

Comment: @Micchaleq modified my answer